Wrapping a paragraph inside a heading behaves different in an iframe vs directly in the page
While I know wrapping a paragraph inside a heading like this:
<h1><p>Lorem<br>Ipsum</p></h1>

is invalid (see this question for example), it still renders correctly in all major browsers.
But as soon as I load the page inside an iFrame, it does break up the heading like you would usually expect the browser to do, rendering something like this:
<h1></h1><p>Lorem<br>Ipsum</p>

Why does that behave differently in an iFrame?

Can you please provide a proper example that reproduces this? Because with something like https://jsfiddle.net/h7cuq5m8/, I can't see the difference.

The most likely answer is that you have a different or missing DOCTYPE in the iframe, but with out the full code it is different to say.

Can you please check my HTML structure with Doctype and correct markup, may be solve your problams

@DavidBradshaw thanks, you were right, it was not the iFrames fault.

In fact the problem is not the iFrame, but the PHP proxy supplying the iFrames content. I forgot that I included HTML parsing in that proxy to be able to inject a custom base tag and CSS.
This proxy uses DOMDocuments loadHTML and saveHTML methods which seems to convert the content to valid HTML.
So it's not the browser being incosistent, it's due to the proxy.

No. Or at least in part: your HTML is invalid. A <h1> element cannot contain a <p> and browsers will do the best they can with your error.

@Rob please read the question again, I know it's invalid. I was just wondering why the browser handled it inconsistently.

Here’s a simple example below:
Main HTML Document:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Invalid HTML Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><p>Lorem<br>Ipsum</p></h1>
</body>
</html>

Embedded in Iframe:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Iframe</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="iframe-content.html" style="width: 100%; height: 180px;border:none;"></iframe>
</body>
</html>

iframe-content.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Invalid HTML Inside Iframe</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        <p>Lorem<br>Ipsum</p>
    </h1>
</body>
</html>

